# "glide get" and "go get" install different versions

Tags: go

I use [`ginkgo`](http://onsi.github.io/ginkgo/) for the test tool, and [`glide`](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide) for the package manager.

`ginkgo` requires that we install a binary to generate test files automatically. `glide`, to the best of my knowledge, does not support the installation of binaries. So, I ended up using `go get` to install the binary, along with its source files.

A problem is that `glide` installs all the packages that it resolves by scanning the go files. This means that the source files of `ginkgo` are also installed. 
During the compilation, the packages in `vendor` directory is prioritized. So this causes the situation where binary from `$GOPATH/bin` is used, and source files from `vendor` directory are used.
And it seems that `go get` fetches files from master branch, where as `glide` fetches the latest released version. So the test files that are generated by the binary is not compatible with the source files installed by glide.

Is there any way to prevent glide from installing some specific packages?
Or are there any other better ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With glide you can specify a certain version of the package you want to install. This is done in the glide.yaml

> TIP: The version is either VCS dependent and can be anything that can
>   be checked out or a semantic version constraint that can be parsed by
>   the github.com/ Masterminds/semver package. For example, with Git this
>   can be a branch, tag, or hash. This varies and depends on what's
>   supported in the VCS.

```
package: github.com/YOUR/PACKAGE
import:
  - package: github.com/onsi/ginkgo/ginkgo
    version: master
    repo: git@github.com:onsi/ginkgo.git
```

This will download the latest master commit.

[Here](https://glide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/versions/) are further information about versioning with glide.

Comment: No problem. I encountered [gopm](https://github.com/gpmgo/gopm) which is able to build binaries after pulling a certain version. But I didn't try it out by myself.